# How to combine the coefficients for multiple regressions into higher levels?

Tags: regression, aggregation

Suppose I want to run a sales model on different segments. For example, I have a food channel, a drug channel, a convenience channel, and a walmart channel. For simplicity, lets assume each channel has 1000 stores. The response variable is sales. The independent variables are various media variables and econometric variables. See below:

$$y_{\text{walmart}_i} = \alpha_{0} + \alpha_{1}x_{i} + \varepsilon_{0}$$
$$y_{\text{drug}_i} = \beta_{0} + \beta_{1}x_{i} + \varepsilon_{1}$$
$$y_{\text{conv}_i} = \gamma_{0} + \gamma_{1}x_{i} + \varepsilon_{2}$$

Suppose I want to aggregate everything to the national level. How do I get a national level coefficient since $$\beta_{1}\text{ and }\beta_{0}$$ is different for each channel? Essentially, this is running a regression with a by group in SAS.

Comment: Could you describe what this aggregate should represent? Suppose the national coefficient of a channel is 5, what does that 5 mean?

Comment: Have you thought about simply using hierarchical regression?

Comment: @Tim I want to get coefficients at the most granular level.

Comment: @dimpol The sum of the three channels is defined as 'National'

Comment: If Iunderstand you correctly, the problem is that you have the values for the sum of the sales of the 3 channels, and now you want to use the $x_i$ to predict the sales of the individual stores/chains?

Comment: @dimpol I want to use the coefficients I get at the lowest level of granularity and combine them so I get a coefficient at a more aggregate level.

Comment: Couldn't you just use summation to aggregate?